# Weird Behaviors of time in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

When I post a message, the time is displayed correctly (the desired time zone). Once I refresh the browser, the time is distorted.
I checked the console and the DB table and I got even more confused.
I both checked the local and Heroku environments.

[image]
[image]

current setting:

on Heroku Console,

`heroku config:add TZ="Asia/Seoul"`

in application.rb

```
config.time_zone = 'Seoul'

config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Seoul'
```

Is there anything I need to fix?

**Update**
I deleted the time zone setting in application.rb, and now
Time.now = +0900
Time.zone.now = +00:00

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262825/why-does-this-rails-query-behave-differently-depending-on-timezone), no matter how set the timezone in the config file, will rails DB always use UTC timezone?

Comment: In Rails, datetime is saved to DB as UTC. In your records, time is mistakenly saved as localtime. Therefore, 9hours is added when displaying, although it is actually localtime. Try removing "config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Seoul'".

Comment: It seems like the DB's timezone is out of sync, but simply deleting the timezone config in application.rb didn't solve the problem yet.

Comment: Are you setting time_zones based on user settings anywhere in your application?  Time zones are such a pain in the butt sometimes ;)

Comment: No. Yes it seems like so :(

Comment: Yes, the DB will always save as UTC, a standard format.  This is FINE, what should be happening is that rails will convert that standard UTC time to a user-friendly displayed value based on the `config.time_zone` you've set... What are you using to display the `created_at` in the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the problem.

```
heroku config:add TZ="Asia/Seoul"
```

in **application.rb**

```
config.time_zone = 'Seoul'

config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

Then, Time.zone.now == Time.now

I will update this later with details.